# Pass HTML to a nested Livewire component and render it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

Is it possible to pass and render HTML tags between Livewire components?

For example, if I have a parent component that renders a nested hero component, is it possible to pass a variable like `$hero_text` from the parent that might include and render a `<br>` tag or something?

Like the equivalent of using the `<<<'HTML'` notation from within the class files that are created for livewire component.

This doesn't work, but an example of what I'm thinking of would be:

```
@livewire('components.hero', [
            'img' => '/img/index/hero-wide.jpg',
            'hero_text' =>
                <<<'HTML'
                    <h1 class="text-3xl">This is header text</h1>
                    <p class="text-sm">This is subheader text</h1>
                HTML
                ])
```

The above would obviously just break, and passing something like:

```
'hero_text' => 'This is upper text <br> This is lower text'
```

would print the `<br>` as text and not render the HTML.

The use case would be for a hero that can have a variety of different text configurations within it without having to create three or four different `$hero_text_1`, `$hero_text_2` parameters that render based on if statements.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is a bit strange and it will be useful to see a sample of the child component.
Also I don't understand why you use *return* to pass the HTML data to the child component (I suppose it's a typo **and now I see that you fixed it**).

Anyway the answer is simple: with blade you can echo unescaped data using the `{!! $text !!}` notation instead of the usual `{{ $text }}` notation:

- parent blade

```html
@livewire('components.hero', [
          'img' => '.....',
          'hero_text' => <<<'HTML'
               <h1 class="text-3xl">This is header text</h1>
               <p class="text-sm">This is subheader text</p>
           HTML
])
```

- components.hero

```html
<div>

    <img src="{{ $img }}">

    {!! $hero_text !!}

</div>
```